# Pandas conditional outer join based on timedelta (merge_asof)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, timedelta

I have multiple dataframes that I need to merge into a single dataset based on a unique identifier (uid), and on the timedelta between dates in each dataframe.

Here's a simplified example of the dataframes:

df1

```
   uid    tx_date last_name first_name  meas_1
0   60 2004-01-11      John      Smith     1.3
1   60 2016-12-24      John      Smith     2.4
2   61 1994-05-05     Betty      Jones     1.2
3   63 2006-07-19     James       Wood     NaN
4   63 2008-01-03     James       Wood     2.9
5   65 1998-10-08       Tom      Plant     4.2
6   66 2000-02-01     Helen       Kerr     1.1
```

df2

```
   uid    rx_date last_name first_name meas_2
0   60 2004-01-14      John      Smith      A
1   60 2017-01-05      John      Smith     AB
2   60 2017-03-31      John      Smith    NaN
3   63 2006-07-21     James       Wood      A
4   64 2002-04-18      Bill    Jackson      B
5   65 1998-10-08       Tom      Plant     AA
6   65 2005-12-01       Tom      Plant      B
7   66 2013-12-14     Helen       Kerr      C
```

Basically I am trying to merge records for the same person from two separate sources, where there link between records for unique individuals is the 'uid', and the link between rows (where it exists) for each individiual is a fuzzy relationship between 'tx_date' and 'rx_date' that can (usually) be accomodated by a specific time delta. There won't always be an exact or fuzzy match between dates, data could be missing from any column except 'uid', and each dataframe will contain a different but intersecting subset of 'uid's.

I need to be able to concatenate rows where the 'uid' columns match, and where the absolute time delta between 'tx_date' and 'rx_date' is within a given range (e.g. max delta of 14 days). Where the time delta is outside that range, or one of either 'tx_date' or 'rx_date' is missing, or where the 'uid' exists in only one of the dataframes, I still need to retain the data in that row. The end result should be something like:

```
    uid    tx_date    rx_date first_name last_name  meas_1 meas_2
0    60 2004-01-11 2004-01-14       John     Smith     1.3      A
1    60 2016-12-24 2017-01-05       John     Smith     2.4     AB
2    60        NaT 2017-03-31       John     Smith     NaN    NaN
3    61 1994-05-05        NaT      Betty     Jones     1.2    NaN
4    63 2006-07-19 2006-07-21      James      Wood     NaN      A
5    63 2008-01-03        NaT      James      Wood     NaN    NaN
6    64 2002-04-18        NaT       Bill   Jackson     NaN      B
7    65 1998-10-08 1998-10-08        Tom     Plant     4.2     AA
8    65        NaT 2005-12-01        Tom     Plant     NaN      B
9    66 2000-02-01        NaT      Helen      Kerr     1.1    NaN
10   66        NaT 2013-12-14      Helen      Kerr     NaN      C
```

Seems like [pandas.merge_asof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341330/pd-merge-asof-fails-with-valueerror-left-keys-must-be-sorted-on-second-run) should be useful here, but I've not been able to get it to do quite what I need.

Trying merge_asof on two of the real dataframes I have gave an error `ValueError: left keys must be sorted`

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341330/pd-merge-asof-fails-with-valueerror-left-keys-must-be-sorted-on-second-run) the problem there was actually due to there being NaT values in the 'date' column for some rows. I dropped the rows with NaT values, and sorted the 'date' columns in each dataframe, but the result still isn't quite what I need.

The code below shows the steps taken.

```
import pandas as pd


df1['date'] = df1['tx_date']
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1['date'] = df1['date'].dropna()
df1 = df1.sort_values('date')

df2['date'] = df2['rx_date']
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df2['date'] = df2['date'].dropna()
df2 = df2.sort_values('date')

df_merged = (pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='date', by='uid', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('14 days'))).sort_values('uid')
```

Result:

```
   uid    tx_date    rx_date last_name_x first_name_x  meas_1 meas_2
3   60 2004-01-11 2004-01-14        John        Smith     1.3      A
6   60 2016-12-24 2017-01-05        John        Smith     2.4     AB
0   61 1994-05-05        NaT       Betty        Jones     1.2    NaN
4   63 2006-07-19 2006-07-21       James         Wood     NaN      A
5   63 2008-01-03        NaT       James         Wood     2.9    NaN
1   65 1998-10-08 1998-10-08         Tom        Plant     4.2     AA
2   66 2000-02-01        NaT       Helen         Kerr     1.1    NaN
```

It looks like a left join rather than a full outer join, so anywhere there's a row in df2 without a match on 'uid' and 'date' in df1 is lost (and it's not really clear from this simplified example, but I also need to add the rows back in where the date was NaT).

Is there some way to achieve a lossless merge, either by somehow doing an outer join with merge_asof, or using some other approach?

Comment: [conditonal_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) might be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

[conditonal_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) handles inequality joins and should help with your use case:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

out = (df1.conditional_join(
             # create temporary columns to handle the 14 day window
             df2.assign(start=df2.rx_date - pd.Timedelta(days=14), 
                        end = df2.rx_date), 
       # column from the left, column from the right, operator
       ('uid','uid', '=='), 
       ('tx_date', 'start', '>='), 
       ('tx_date', 'end', '<='), 
       how='outer')
)
out['left'] = out['left'].fillna(out.right)
res={'uid':out.left.uid,
     'tx_date':out.left.tx_date, 
     'rx_date':out.right.rx_date,
     'first_name':out.left.first_name, 
     'last_name':out.left.last_name,
     'meas_1':out.left.meas_1,
     'meas_2':out.right.meas_2}

pd.DataFrame(res).sort_values(['uid','tx_date'])

     uid              tx_date    rx_date first_name last_name  meas_1 meas_2
3   60.0  2004-01-11 00:00:00 2004-01-14      Smith      John     1.3      A
4   60.0  2016-12-24 00:00:00 2017-01-05      Smith      John     2.4     AB
7   60.0                  NaN 2017-03-31      Smith      John     NaN    NaN
0   61.0  1994-05-05 00:00:00        NaT      Jones     Betty     1.2    NaN
5   63.0  2006-07-19 00:00:00 2006-07-21       Wood     James     NaN      A
1   63.0  2008-01-03 00:00:00        NaT       Wood     James     2.9    NaN
8   64.0                  NaN 2002-04-18    Jackson      Bill     NaN      B
6   65.0  1998-10-08 00:00:00 1998-10-08      Plant       Tom     4.2     AA
9   65.0                  NaN 2005-12-01      Plant       Tom     NaN      B
2   66.0  2000-02-01 00:00:00        NaT       Kerr     Helen     1.1    NaN
10  66.0                  NaN 2013-12-14       Kerr     Helen     NaN      C
```